# How to configure the MIGS Omnipay gateway?

Tags: omnipay

I'm trying to combine MIGS and [omnipay](https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension).

Steps
1. Download omnipay 2.5 https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension

```
sudo -u apache wget https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/archive/2.5.zip
sudo -u apache curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo -u apache php
sudo mkdir /usr/share/httpd/.composer
sudo chown apache /usr/share/httpd/.composer
```

2. Unzip into files/civicrm/ext
3. Require MIGS: sudo -u apache ./composer.phar -v require omnipay/migs

I had to do a bit of hacking about. php7.0 and some dependency troubles.

- Edit vendor/omnipay/tests/composer.json - make dev

  ```
  sudo -u apache mkdir /srv/web/docdownload.com.au/web/files/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor-2.5/vendor/sebastian/global-state/src
  sudo -u apache mkdir /srv/web/docdownload.com.au/web/files/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor-2.5/vendor/sebastian/comparator/src
  sudo -u apache mkdir /srv/web/docdownload.com.au/web/files/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor-2.5/vendor/sebastian/diff/src/
  ```

Result

```
Using version ^2.2 for omnipay/migs                 
./composer.json has been updated
```

The omnipay extension is registered.

4. Registering MIGS with omnipay. I want an on-site, pass by xml processor.

I created a file Metadata/omnipay_Migs_TwoParty.mgd.php, cleared caches.  I tried registering the payments processor and cannot see it in the list. Administration > System Settings > payment processors - civicrm/admin/paymentProcessor.

What goes into the metadata file omnipay_Migs_TwoParty.mgd.php? Has anybody created one before? Is there a document reference? Reverse engineer? Debug until it works? I created the minimum.

```
 return array(
   array(
    'name' => 'OmniPay - Migs_TwoParty',
    'entity' => 'payment_processor_type',
    'metadata' => array(
  ),
  'params' => array(
    'version' => 3,
    'title' => 'OmniPay - Migs_TwoParty',
    'name' => 'omnipay_Migs_TwoParty',
    'description' => 'Omnipay Migs_TwoParty Onsite processing',
    // DO NOT CHANGE: Labels are used as Omnipay gateway properties.
    'user_name_label' => 'Api Key',
    'password_label' => 'Password',
    // When ready we need to add signature_label & figure out how to pass through to tpl.
    //'signature_label' => 'Public Key (if wishing to use Client Encryption - recommended)',
    'class_name' => 'Payment_OmnipayMultiProcessor',
    'url_site_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_api_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_recur_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_site_test_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_recur_test_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_api_test_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'billing_mode' => 1,
    'payment_type' => 1,
    'is_recur' => 1,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work with the following meta-data file. omnipay_Migs_TwoParty.mgd.php. Since the field in the code is merchantAccessCode I changed the label for passwords to "Merchant access code'. Both the debugger and the error message show this.

```
return [
 [ 
   'name' => 'OmniPay - MIGS',
   'entity' => 'payment_processor_type',
   'params' => array(
     'version' => 3,
     'title' => 'OmniPay - MIGS',
     'name' => 'Migs_TwoParty',
     'description' => 'Omnipay MIGS',
     // DO NOT CHANGE: Labels are used as Omnipay gateway properties.
    'user_name_label' => 'Merchant Id',
    'password_label' => 'Merchant access code',
    'signature_label' => 'Secure Hash',
    'class_name' => 'Payment_OmnipayMultiProcessor',
    'url_site_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_api_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_recur_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_site_test_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_recur_test_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'url_api_test_default' => 'http://unused.com',
    'billing_mode' => 1,
    'payment_type' => 1,
    'is_recur' => 1,
   ),
 ]
];
```